# Neo4j APOC trigger and Manual Index on Relationship Properties

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'd like to setup Neo4j APOC trigger that will add all relationship properties to manual index, something like the following:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('HAS_VALUE_ON_INDEX',"UNWIND {createdRelationships} AS r MATCH (Decision)-[r:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(Characteristic) CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r,['property_1','property_2']) RETURN count(*)", {phase:'after'})
```

The issue is that I don't know the exact set of `HAS_VALUE_ON` relationship properties because I use the dynamic properties approach with Spring Data Neo4 5.

Is it possible to change this trigger declaration to be able to add all of the `HAS_VALUE_ON` relationship properties(existing and ones that will be created in future) to the manual index instead of the preconfigured ones( like `['property_1','property_2']` in the mentioned example) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not know the set of properties in advance, then you can use the [`keys`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-keys) function to add all properties of the created relationships to the index:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
  'HAS_VALUE_ON_INDEX',
  'UNWIND {createdRelationships} AS r MATCH (Decision)-[r:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(Characteristic) 
   CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r, keys(r)) RETURN count(*)',
   {phase:'after'}
)
```